# Django do a simple group by / count statement

Tags: python, django, django-models, dry, django-orm

Let's say I have the following:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
  (1, "Choice 1"),
  (2, "Choice 2"),
  (3, "Choice 3"),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, )
  category = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

Now, what I'd like to do is group by category and get the number of instances for each group. For instance, I'd like to get a result like this:

```
Choice 1: 31 Instances
Choice 2: 4 Instances
Choice 3: 2 Intances
```

This can be done with the following query:

```
group_by_category = MyModel.objects.values('category').distinct().annotate(count=Count('category'))
```

The above works however because the `values()` will return a ValueQuerySet (which contains dicts instead of MyModel instances). So I am *not* able to use "get_category_display" to output "Choice 1", "Choice 2" etc, but I can only print the numbers.

Is there a DRY way to be able to use the `get_category_display` method ?

I know that I can add the display value myself using a for loop to modify each dict (if category=='1' then its display value is "Choice 1" etc) however I don't feel that's DRY enough.

Comment: It could be better to have a second model for your categories instead of using choices.

Comment: @RodrigoOlmo I am aware of that however I don't want to change my database schema right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dict(MY_CHOICES)[1]
"Choice 1"
```

Why `distinct()`? Does it do anything in this case?